# For loop equivalent RTL description

Tags: vhdl, verilog, register-transfer-level

Coming from a software background, it is still hard for me to think hardware.
What would be the equivalent of a for loop in RTL language (VHDL or Verilog) ? I guess I need one register to build a counter, and a multiplexer for branching, is it ?

Comment: In VHDL a loop statement with a for iteration scheme with a static loop parameter specification is synthesis eligible. A loop statement presents as a sequence of statements repeated 0 or more times with the loop parameter set to each discrete iteration value. Perhaps you should demonstrate a problem you're trying to solve and an actual error?

Comment: verilog has 'for' loops as well with some limitations for synthesizability. you need to state our real issue.

Comment: *"I guess I need..."* No. Also have a look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377657/is-this-matrix-vector-multiplication-function-in-vhdl-parallelized) where there are two nested loops in VHDL.

Answer (score 2):

A VHDL `process` or Verilog *always block* is *a little bit of software that models a little bit of hardware*. A process has a *sensitivity list*: this is the list of inputs. Should any of these change, then process (ie the *little bit of software*) executes and the output(s) of the process (any *signal* driven by that process) get(s) assigned.

For *combinational logic*, any input always results in the same output, hence you can write a truth table. Your *little bit of software* is describing the truth table. You could do this using a *case statement* but that would be impractical for a large number of inputs. Instead, we use some other software-style constructs, such as *if statements*, *loops*, *arithmetic operators* and so on. The purpose of a *logic synthesiser* is to design a *little bit of hardware* that behaves in exactly the same way as your *little bit of software*. In doing this, the logic synthesiser could evaluate your *little bit of sofware* to determine it's truth table and then could design its *little bit of hardware* based on that. However, a real logic synthesiser will use a variety of techniques to achieve the same thing.

So, if you put a *for loop* in your process, if your *little bit of software* includes a loop, then you will just get a block combinational logic. The *for loop* will determine the behaviour of that block. Because of the nature of a *for loop* (and because of the way in which your logic synthesiser probably goes about designing its *little bit of hardware*), that combination logic will probably contain repeated structures. That may be important when you consider how that block will be implemented, particularly on an FPGA. It may be important with regards to the delay through the block. However, the most important thing is that it will be a block of combinational logic.

Comment: This is a comment really, but it is far too long.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realise is that an HDL language has two different faces.

- The one you see in simulation.
- The one you so after synthesis.

In simulation the `for` loop is the same as in most languages: the instructions in the for loop get executed a number of times.

To convert the loop into logic (thus for synthesis) the first requirement is that the loop size must be know during compile time. Thus you can loop from `0 to a_const`. But you can't loop from `0 to variable_whos_value_can_change`.

From there the for loop becomes simple: any logic implemented inside the for loop is repeated.

Thus `for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) A[i] = B[i] + C[i]` makes 4 adders. All of these operate in parallel.

```
always @( * ) 
begin
   max = c[0];
   for (n=1; n<10; n++)
     if (c[n]>max) max = c[n];
end
```

This makes a block of combinatorial logic in which 10 values of c enter and at the output max equals to the largest c. Note that no registers or clock are involved.

Comment: I see. I guess I have to give more details on my problem. I'm using chisel to build a matrix multiplier. At the beginning, what I did was that I just implemented the matrix multiplier algorithm but people told me that I should not do that way. Why ? Because I can't multiply and add Inside of my loops, otherwise it would generate tons of logic gates to perform the operation in one cycle. So what I have to do is to divide the code into different blocks (an accumulator, a multiplier…) that I should wire togoether. I was wondering if I still had to use my for loops to calculate the indexes :/

Comment: In other words, `for` loops are used to *generate* X cells, not to perform an operation X times, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, and those X cells can be X-times combinatorial logic, but you can just as well  generate X registers that way. *"not to perform an operation X times"* That is a matter of nomenclature. You **do** effectively perform the operation X times, but using X individual logic blocks, not using one logic block X-times.

Comment: Then how do you use this logic bloc X times, do you have to implement counters, keep track of indexes in registers etc... ?