# Setting entire register array to zero

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to set all the registers in the array to zero. However, I've parametrized the sizing of the array:

```
logic [WIDTH-2:0] numelem [0:MAXBITS-1];
```

Is there a way where I could essentially do `numelem <= {0,0,0,0,...}` but for a generic size? The method preferably needs to be non-blocking since I need to do the assignment within an `always_ff` block. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1) As Oldfart suggested, use a for loop; its simple and easy to understand

```
int i;
...
for (i = 0; i < MAXBITS; i = i + 1) begin
  numelem[i] <= '0;
end
```

2) Use array assignment pattern with the `default` keyword:

```
numelem <= '{default: '0};
```

3) Use `bit` type instead of `logic` type if you dont need to simulate `'bx` or `'bz` states; variables of type `bit` are initialized to `'b0` instead of `'bx`.

Answer (score 1):

I am in favor of using the old fashioned for loop:

```
int c;
   ...
   for (c=0; c<MAXBITS; c=c+1) numelem [c] <= 'b0;
```

Comment: In your experience, will this be performed in parallel? I have shied away from using a for-loop since I wasn't sure if the compilers will infer the inside logic to be in parallel.

Comment: @ripa it depends on whether this is for simulation or synthesis. In the former, this will imply hardware that clears all the registers of `numelem` in parallel. In the latter, the code will execute sequentially but unless `MAXBITS` is huge, this shouldnt be a big concern.

Comment: yes, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080369/for-loop-equivalent-rtl-description/59087499#59087499).

Answer (score 1):

```
logic [WIDTH-2:0] numelem [0:MAXBITS-1] = '{default:'0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in with another option which can be used for comparison as well:

```
signal = {$bits(signal){1'b0}};
signal == {$bits(signal){1'b0}}; // This will evaluate to true
```